# Comment traduire « they had it/we all have it comin' » : du spécifique au proverbial ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

**Avertissement** : divulgâcheur/*spoilers* (film *Unforgiven*, 1992)

---

> (1) Kid: You know how I said I shot five men? It weren't true. That
> Mexican who come at me with a knife? I just busted his leg with a
> shovel. I didn't kill him or nothin' neither.
>  (2) Will: Well, you
> sure killed the hell outta that fella today.
>  (3) Kid: Hell yeah!
> I killed the hell out of him, didn't I? Three shots and he was takin'
> a shit!
>  (4) Will: Take a drink, kid.
>  (5) Kid: Jesus Christ!
> It don't seem real. Guy ain't gonna never breathe again ever. Now he's
> dead, and the other one too, all on account of pullin' a trigger.
> (6) Will: It's a hell of a thing, killin' a man. You take away all
> he's got and all he's ever gonna have.
>  (7) Kid: Yeah. Well, I
> guess **they had it comin'**.
>  (8) Will: **We all have it comin'**,
> kid.

Voici un échange de la toute fin, où le film vient peut-être nuancer l'idée *du mérite, de mériter* qu'on se fait de prime abord de l'[expression](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+coming) (*ils l'ont bien mérité*) :

> (9) Bill Daggett: I don't deserve this — to die like this. I was
> building a house.
>  (10) Will: Deserve's got nothing to do with
> it. [aims gun]
>  (11) Little Bill: I'll see you in hell, William
> Munny!
>  (12) Will: Yeah. [fires]
>
> [ [*Unforgiven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unforgiven), Clint Eastwood, 1992, sur [wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Unforgiven) ] <sup>1</sup>

C'est qu'en plus quand on dit qu'*ils l'ont bien mérité*, avec un fait passé, ex post facto, on comprend, mais quand je veux dire que c'est le cas de tout le monde (et toujours), je ne trouve pas de formulation adéquate.

---

Comment traduit-on le *(7)they had it comin'/(8)we all have it comin'* en s'appuyant sur le contexte, le registre ; y a-t-il une manière plus usuelle de traduire qu'avec [*l'avoir bien mérité*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%A9riter/50640/locution) ; comment s'attaque-t-on à la difficulté particulière avec (8), le cas échéant, quand on parle plus généralement et qu'on se concentre moins sur un fait précis, sur le passé etc. ?

---

<sup>1. Voici ma traduction en français du Québec, avec un registre très
familier, sinon vulgaire (jurons), et écrit de manière à refléter l'oral ; une manière de cerner le contexte différemment, mais dont la lecture n'est pas requise pour répondre à la question :</sup>

> <sup>(1) Kid : Tu sais
> quand j'ai dit que j'ai tiré cinq gars l'aut' jour ? C'tait pas vrai.
> T'sais Le mexicain qui m'avait foncé dessus avec el'couteau ? J'i'ai
> juste pèté la jambe avec une pelle. J'l'ai pas tué ou rien de
> même.
>  (2) Will : Ben, en tous cas tu l'as crissément ben tué c'te
> gars-là aujourd'hui, j'ten passe un papier.
>  (3) Kid : Maudit que
> oui! J'l'ai-tu pas ben tué, sacrament ? Trois coups pis là i'était en
> train de chier!
>  (4) Will : Prend un coup, l'jeune.
>  (5) Kid :
> Crisse de tabarnac, ça se peut tu. Le gars va p'u jamais pouvoir
> respirer. Là i'est mort, pis l'autre avec, tout ça parce qu'on a
> appuyé sur un ostie d'piton.
>  (6) Will : C'est ben toute qu'une
> crisse d'affaire que de tuer un homme. Tu 'i prends tout' c'qu'i' a,
> pis tout' c'qu'i pourrait avoir, pour toujours.
>  (7) Kid : Ouais.
> Ben, j'imagine que [they had it comin'].
>  (8) Will : On [have it
> comin'] tous, mon ti-caille.
>  [...]
>  (9) Little Bill :
> J'mérite pas ça —  d'mourir de même. J'me construisais une maison mo[é]-là.
>
> (10) Will : Le mérite i'a rien 'avoir là-dedans mon homme. [*il
> vise*]
>  (11) Little Bill : On va s'revoir en enfer, William
> Munny.
>  (12) Will : 'Oua[is]. [*il tire*]</sup>

Comment: Nothing to deal with the question but am I wrong to think "It don't seem real" should be "It do**es**n't seem real" ?

Comment: @Random Formellement peut-être, mais c'est bien usuel avec certains registres, voir cette [réponse](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/40102/16335) sur _ELL_.

Comment: @LUNA Thank you. As I had stated, please consider making an answer out of what you were talking about. Consider what was the _object_ of both verbs; now consider a known variation of that expression with a negative spin to it; now consider the inevitability of the negative spin alone. You can deconstruct that very expression like that or something, and I believe it would make for an interesting read, so don't hesitate! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To have it coming* est considéré comme un synonyme de *"to deserve"*, que ce soit en bien (*"we worked so hard to make the business succeed that I think we have it coming"*) ou en mal (*"the jury felt the guy had it coming, so they didn't convict her of attacking him"*). L'utilisation "en mal" semble tout de même plus fréquente.

Certaines traductions possibles de *they had it coming* sont :

- ils l'ont bien mérité (connotation positive ou négative)
- ils ne l'ont pas volé (connotation plus souvent négative)
- ils l'ont bien cherché (connotation négative)

Les deux dernières sont particulièrement appropriées, car elles gardent un côté légèrement informel, populaire.

L'expression en anglais, au présent (*you have it coming*), semble construite de manière à exprimer que, tu es *en train* de faire quelque chose (*you are doing something*) qui mérite une réponse, une conséquence, laquelle est *en train* de venir. Et plus tu persistes dans ton acte, plus la conséquence se rapproche. Mais si tu arrêtes, alors la conséquence ne viendra pas. C'est ainsi que je comprends l'expression.

Si je me base sur ma compréhension de l'expression pour analyser ton exemple, la réponse du deuxième personnage (8) semble jouer sur le mélange entre une généralité (*"Everyone deserves a punishment"*) et une menace imminente qui est *en train* d'arriver (*"Something (that punishment) is coming to get us"*). Peut-être fait-il référence à la mort elle-même, étant donné que la punition pour les autres hommes dont il parle était la mort.

Source : http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+it+coming

Comment: Merci ! La menace imminente, donc l'élément temporel, _en train_. Je pense que vous avez les outils dans ce dernier para. pour traduire (8)...

Answer (score 1):

En règle générale je traduis "*They had it coming*" par "*Ils l'avaient bien cherché*"

Mais le "*We all have it coming*", complique la chose, c'est une extension d'une expression idiomatique qu'on peut pas traduire en utilisant la même expression en français.

Comment: Pourquoi pas : - "C'est tout ce qu'ils méritaient..." - "C'est ce qu'on mérite tous" ?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps oui, "mériter" semble bien marcher avec la 2ème phrase. Si la première phrase était toute seule par contre, "ils l'avaient bien cherché" semble mieux

Comment: @exilanceéglisée le problème, c'est que dire "chercher" puis "mériter" sonne faux, ça casse le lien entre les 2 phrases...

Comment: @exilanceéglisée J'imagine que le 3e commentaire m'est adressé, et j'avoue que je n'avais pas de bonne traduction pour le (8). La version de Simon Déchamps est très intéressante et me convient, surtout pour la deuxième partie, elle illustre bien le concept. En réalité, je pense qu'il serait intéressant de poser la question sur le SE English, leur demander ce qu'il comprennent exactement dans la (8), comment ils la reformuleraient. Pour ma part, "they had it coming" est une expression que je connais de contexte, sans vraiment me penser sur sa signification réelle est ses possibles étirements

Comment: D'ailleurs c'est peut être bête, mais ça serait pas intéressant de chercher dans la VF du film comment ça a été traduit ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas vraiment de raison pour laquelle on ne pourrait pas dire "nous l'avons tous bien cherché" (ou, plus formellement, "on l'avait tous bien cherché"). L'espression ne se limite pas à une seule personne: "vous l'avez bien cherché", "je l'avais bien cherché", "ils l'auront bien cherché" sont toutes des formes correctes

Answer (score 1):

L'expression "l'avoir bien cherché" reflète exactement ce que tu veux. On dit que quelqu'un *l'a bien cherché* quand il subit les conséquences néfastes de ses actes malveillants. Ici on pourrait traduire:

> (7) Kid : Ouais. Ben, j'imagine qu'ils l'avaient bien cherché.
>
> (8) Will : On l'a tous bien cherché, mon ti-caille.

L'expression en elle-même reflète le fait que les actions soient passées ("on l'a bien cherché" est du passé composé, "ils l'avaient bien cherché" est du passé antérieur)

"On" est en général utilisé à la place de "nous" dans la langue orale quand il s'agit de registre courant ou familier, il est donc à privilégier ici.

Comment: En relisant ma réponse, je me suis aperçu que j'avais écrit beaucoup de bêtises. Tout devrait être corrigé et mieux expliqué.

Answer (score 1):

J’aime bien les trois autres réponses, surtout  qu’ils proposent: “[ils l'ont **bien cherché**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/comment-traduire-they-had-it-we-all-have-it-comin-du-sp%C3%A9cifique-au-prover/22773#22773)” et/ou “[Ils l'avaient **bien cherché**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/comment-traduire-they-had-it-we-all-have-it-comin-du-sp%C3%A9cifique-au-prover/22768#22768)" (et [encore une fois ici avec l'imparfait](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/comment-traduire-they-had-it-we-all-have-it-comin-du-sp%C3%A9cifique-au-prover/22778#22778)) pour “**they had** it coming”(7), qui captent bien, je trouve, le sens de *mérite/mériter* que l’on associe normalement avec  l'expression anglaise.

Je préfère “avoir **cherché**” pour #(7) car ça me permet d’employer/juxtaposer (d’une manière opposée à “chercher” ) le mot “trouver” pour interpréter #(8) comme je suis tenté de l’interpréter :

> (7) Kid : Ouais. Ben, j'imagine qu’ils l'ont/avaient bien cherché.
>
> **(8) Will : On va tous la(/le/en) trouver [un jour], mon ti-caille.**

Cette interprétation de #(8) est basée, bien entendu, sur l’idée géniale dans la dernière phrase d’une des autres réponses que:

> “Peut-être fait-il référence à la mort elle-même, étant donné que la
>   punition pour les autres hommes dont il parle était la mort.”

Cependant, je ne vois pas “**la** mort” (ou donc **l[e]**’ensemble de “prends tout' c'qu'i' a, pis tout' c'qu'i pourrait avoir, pour toujours” [= “**en**”?]) (qui va être trouvé par nous tous) employé/e ici  forcement pour dire “punition” en comparison avec ce que les 2 autres hommes ont subit, mais peut-être seulement pour constater que, littéralement, “On va tous y passer [par là]” ou “La mort nous arrive/vient [à tous]” = “It [death]’s gonna come/happen to all of us, kid.”/”We’ve all got it coming our way. kid.”

Comment: @exilanceéglisée I was trying to say that, imo^, (8) is actually NOT using the expression AT ALL & that the words are meant to be taken literally ("we all have death [coming] in our future/on our horizon") & therefore should be translated literally^^ & not taken/translated w/the expression’s figurative meaning of “we deserved it” in mind...(to be continued to provide "footnotes" to go w/the "^" & "^^" to try to explain: ^why I think (8) isn't an instance of the words being used figuratively as part of the expression & ^^why I tried to work the word "trouver" into my literal French translation)

Comment: @exilanceéglisée (continued from above)......^(imo, the full expression includes the notion of “[coming] TO HIM/THEM/US” & when used in the past tense w/“had” (as it usually is) the “to him/etc” is clearly understood & can be omitted, whereas in the present/future tense (where the expression is less often used), the omission of “to him/us” is a signal (to me) that the literal meaning is/could be intended)…...^^[I picked “la/le/en trouver” for (8) in French simply to “play off” of “chercher” in (7), just as (8) in English is, imo, “playing off” the figurative use of the words in (7)

Comment: Thanks. I think (8) is different too. More than a mere change of scope with the same expression in any case. The construction you put forward with _trouver_ isn't sufficient for me to convey death imho i.e. it would not be typical for me the read in anything like that from the verb in context, even with (7) before. Maybe you would need "tous vont devoir un jour y faire face" or sth. like that. But I consider "on va tous y passer" trumps all, and it's idiomatic and captures the "reshaping" that Will has done of the idiom/litteral use thereof, imho. +1

Comment: Je sais que c'est pas génial de faire ce genre de commentaires, mais pourquoi les trois derniers commentaires sont en français ? La réponse et la question sont en français et normalement si un anglophone comprends la question il n'a pas besoin d'avoir des réponses en anglais.

Comment: @exilanceéglisée oui, je réalise maintenant qu'il y avait des commentaires qui ont depuis été supprimés et les réponses n'ont plus le même sens sans eux.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat OP made a comment in French (subsequently deleted) that indicated to me that my Fr answer had been unclear on a point. I responded w/2 comments in Eng to make it easier for me to try to clarify the point & the OP then kindly switched to Eng. My biggest error was using comments (in whatever language) instead of editing my answer (in whatever lang) to try to clarify. (I do misuse comments). Comments can be confusing 'cause of limits placed on them & evidence of this is even present in your comment, for I don't get why you said “pourquoi...sont en **français**”(in whatever lang).

Comment: @PapaPoule Lapsus sûrement, je voulais évidemment dire en anglais, j'ai peut-être mélangé avec "pas en français"